# Convergence in quotient topological vector space

Tags: functional-analysis, topological-vector-spaces

Let $X$ be a Hausdorff topological vector space and $N$ be a closed subspace. Consider the quotient topological vector space $X/N$ with natural quotient topology. I want to show the following statement:

If $x_n+N\to x+N$ in $X/N$, then for any representatives $x_n,x$, there exist $y_n\in N$ so that $x_n+y_n\to x$.

My idea for proof is motivated by the simple example: $X=\mathbb R^2$ and $N=\{0\}\times \mathbb R$, in which the result is simple. But how could I proceed in infinite dimensional space?

Comment: If $X$ has a countable fundamental system of $0$-neighborhoods $U_n$ you can use the fact that $q(U_n)$ is a fundamental system of $0$-neighborhoods in $X/N$ (where $q$ is the quotient map). If $X$ is not metrizable I am not very optimistic that the statement is true.

Comment: Thank younfor your comment. The reason i want this is to be true is that I am proving the following theorem: if X is a Frechet space then so is X/N, where N is a closed subspace. But I got stuck when I prove that X/N is complete.